# Basic Question about iPhone Object C Arrays and Deep and Pointer Copy

Tags: macos, nsstring, nsmutablearray, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am new to the iPhone / Mac space and this is probably a pretty basic question, I have done some searching and have not found the direct answer.

I would like to know if the addObject method for Arrays / Mutable Arrays does a shallow (pointer only) or deep (copies object) when adding.

1. A mutable array that has been alloc
2. A NSString that has been alloc with some sort of init
3. We addObject the string to the mutable array
4. We then release the NSString

If this is the proper way to do things, that it is assumed that the addObject will do a deep copy of the NSString.  Just confirming that this is the proper way to do memory management with mutable array ...

Comment: Copying a reference is not a shallow copy.  What `copy` and `mutableCopy` do are shallow copies.   A reference is just a reference.  There can be a million references to an object or just one, in either case it *has no impact whatsoever on the state of the object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addObject:` does a shallow copy. What you're missing is that `NSMutableArray` retains the object, so it does not go away, but does not require a deep copy. This is a key point to Objective-C memory management. You should read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Cocoa memory management is not complicated, and is incredibly consistent. I have a shortened summary at [Three Magic Words](http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6).

Comment: NSArray's `addObject:` doesn't copy anything ever.   A pointer copy is not a ashallow copy.

Comment: Yes, I browsed though it but examples like above are not as clear for adding and removing from collections, etc.  So I can also assume that if a remoteObjectAt is called, the same thing happens, it's retain count is also subtracted by one.  .....  From what I read in the doc this is what happens, just want to make sure.  This is a unique way of doing things compared to other 3gls.  But interesting I guess.  Apple just needs to implement managed memory control on the IOS platforms......

Comment: `removeObject:` does release the object. Typically you shouldn't concern yourself with the internal memory management of other objects. Your job is to retain the things you're keeping track of (usually because they're in an ivar). And honor the naming conventions so you know when you are or are not an owner. I'm not certain what you mean when you compare ObjC to "other 3gls" since there isn't much consistency across them. COBOL, C, C++ and Java all have completely different approaches to memory management. When you say "managed memory control," do you mean garbage collection?

Answer (score 2):

When adding an Object to an Array, its retain count will be increased. A object will be released when its retain count is 0. So when adding the NSString to you anArray it won't be a copy (you can change foo and it will be changed in the array, too) but it will increase foo's retain count by 1.

```
NSString *foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString@"bar"]; // retain count +1
[anArray addObject:foo]; // NOT COPIED, but retain count of 'foo' increased by 1
[foo release]; // retain count of foo decreased by 1
```

When you at some time release anArray, it will call release on its objects. So foo's retain count will finally become 0 and foo will be released.

```
// some time later..
[anArray release]; // anArray released, foo retain count = 0.. foo gets released.
```

Kind Regards,
Christian